# i created facebook application display error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

I created a facebook application: [Dedicated Academy](https://apps.facebook.com/dedicated_academy/), but it displays error everytime when I open it.

Here are my app settings:

> **App Domains** : daplonline.in
>
> **Canvas Page** : apps.facebook.com/dedicated_academy
>
> **Canvas URL** : localhost
>
> **Secure Canvas URL** : daplonline.in

Answer (score 0):

Your **Canvas URL** and **Secure Canvas URL** are incorrect.

Canvas URL must be: http://daplonline.in

Secure Canvas URL must be: https://daplonline.in

But as I can see your website is not SSL certified (you need **https**), your app can not be visible in facebook. **https** is mandatory for a canvas app.

Please don't follow such tutorials who told you to write anything on app settings. Follow the official documentation: http://developers.facebook.com